# Unexpected behaviour when accessing class properties

Tags: php, arrays, oop

If we define a array within a class, and use a method to set the elements, when accessing these elements individually, I cannot seem to print them.

I have setup a quick class to demonstrate this.

method **printArrayZero** returns **Notice:** *Array to string conversion...*

method **printLocal** is how I normally access individual array elements, this seems to work just fine with a local array.

```
class test
{
    var $a = array();

    function fillArray()
    {
        $this->a[0] = 'zero';
        $this->a[1] = 'one';
        $this->a[2] = 'two';
        $this->a[3] = 'three';
        $this->a[4] = 'four';
    }


    function printArrayZero()
    {
       print_r("Stored in element 0 : $this->a[0]");
    }


    function printLocal()
    {
        $t[0] = 'zero';
        $t[1] = 'one';
        $t[2] = 'two';
        $t[3] = 'three';
        $t[4] = 'four';

       print_r("Stored in element 0 : $t[0]");
    }


}
```

$test->printArrayZero() returns result

*Stored in element 0 : Array[0]*

$test->printLocal() returns result

*Stored in element 0 : zero*

I am still relatively new to OOP, I have been programming with PHP procedurally for a while, I have not came across this problem before.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with:

```
function printArrayZero()
{
   print_r('Stored in element 0 : ' . $this->a[0]);
}
```

or:

```
function printArrayZero()
{
   print_r("Stored in element 0 : {$this->a[0]}");
}
```

Comment: For the latter see: http://docs.php.net/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Comment: Yes I can do that but I don't understand why it works locally but not when accessing via the property. I stumbled upon this problem as I have a long string which accesses alot of array elements all inside double quotes, procedurally this worked fine, now it seems I would have to break the quotes for every array element. Edited - Ok I see I must use braces. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yor variable behaving as string part in `print_r` please use this code

```
function printArrayZero(){
   print_r("Stored in element 0 : {$this->a[0]}");
}
```

And Please call `fillArray` method first after that `printArrayZero`
try this code

```
$a = new test();
$a->fillArray();
$a->printArrayZero();
```

Or you can fill array into `__constructor()`,

```
public function __constructor(){
        $this->a[0] = 'zero';
        $this->a[1] = 'one';
        $this->a[2] = 'two';
        $this->a[3] = 'three';
        $this->a[4] = 'four';
}
```

`__constructor` call automaic when you create class object then no need `fillArray` method

```
    $a = new test();
    $a->printArrayZero();
```